# Scala for-yield with multiple conditions

Tags: scala

I have a `bitmap` object that is a 3-dimensional array with third dimension equal to 3. I want to split it into 64x64x3 blocks. For this I have the following code snippet:

```
val tiles: someType = for {

  x <- bitmap.indices by 64
  y <- bitmap(0).indices by 64


  data = for {
    //For all X and Y within one future tile coordinates
    tx <- x until x + 64
    ty <- y until y + 64
  } yield bitmap(tx)(ty)

...
}
```

In the `data` for loop `yield` will cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` at the last chunk. How can I check, whether `x` and `y` don't exceed array borders in this loop? Is it possible to have multiple  `until` conditions for the same variable in the same loop?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, it works! And looks pretty elegant. Before you post an answer, please look at my edit, I replaced `tileSize` with 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
val tiles: someType = for {
  x <- bitmap.indices by 64
  y <- bitmap(0).indices by 64

  data = for {
    //For all X and Y within one future tile coordinates
    tx <- x until math.min(x + 64, bitmap.length)
    ty <- y until math.min(y + 64, bitmap(0).length)
  } yield bitmap(tx)(ty)
}
```